# Basic counting trouble

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose you have $8$ people. How many possible ways can you seat these people if

a) two persons, A and B, must sit together?

b) $4$ men and $4$ women, but no $2$ men and no $2$ women can sit together

c) there are $5$ men who must all sit together

d) there are $4$ married couples that must sit together

I suppose I'm confused as to what my error is on some of these by doing:

a) This makes it so that we are dividing the seating into a group of $2$ and $6$ groups of $1$, so we have $$\frac{8!}{2!}$$ ways to do this. But also we could view this as only having $7$ degrees of freedom, twice, so we'd have $$2 \cdot 7!$$. Which one is correct and why is the other wrong??

b) This one I do not know how to do.

c) Again, is this not just a group of five and three groups of 1? to get
$$\frac{8!}{5!}?$$ Or is it $4! \cdot 5!$ since we have 4 degrees of freedom and $5!$ distinguishable items?

d) Again, is this

$$\frac{8!}{2^4}$$ or is it $4$ groups of $2$ giving $4!2^4$?? Why do both answers here seem right??

Comment: You should state that the people sit in a row, if that is your intention.

Answer (score 1):

Are these circular tables or tables with a distinct orientation.
Based on the way you answered the first question, I am going to guess that these tables have an orientation.

a) 1 group of 2 and 6 groups of 1 is 7 groups total.
$2\cdot 7!$

b) You can but a man at the head or you can put a woman a the head.  Once you have made this decision there are $4!$ to arrange the men and $4!$ ways to arrange the women.

c) there is a group of 5 and 3 groups of 1.  $5!\cdot 4!$

d) 4 groups of 2. $(2!)^44!$

If you descide that this is a circular table.  Then for any of the configurations above, you can always rotate the table such that Mr. Jones is at the head.

Divide the results by $8.$

Comment: I thought a counting principle was that if you have $n$ objects in $r$ groups of sizes $n_1,\ldots, n_r$, then you have $$\frac{n!}{n_1! \cdots n_r!}$$ ways to do this. Why can I not then do $8!/2!$ or $8!/5!$, etc?

Comment: @JohnDD The expression $$\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2! \cdots n_r!}$$ counts the number of arrangements of $n$ objects, of which $n_1$ are of type $1$, $n_2$ of type $2$, and so forth, where $n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_r = n$.  An application of this formula is counting the number of permutations of a word such as ANAGRAM.  There are $$\binom{7}{3}4! = \frac{7!}{3!4!} \cdot 4! = \frac{7!}{3!}$$ such permutations since the three As are identical.  However, in the first problem, persons A and B are distinct, so this formula is not applicable.